# Count emojis in pivot table in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, pivot-table, spreadsheet

I have the following table in my google spreadsheet:

| timestamp | emoji |
| --- | --- |
| 03.03.2021 01:07:45 |  |
| 03.03.2021 16:17:45 |  |
| 03.03.2021 17:01:45 | ⛈ |
| 03.03.2021 17:02:45 |  |
| 03.03.2021 17:03:45 | ☀️ |
| 04.03.2021 18:17:45 | ⛈ |
| 04.03.2021 16:17:45 |  |
| 04.03.2021 17:02:45 |  |
| 04.03.2021 18:17:45 |  |
| 04.03.2021 18:27:45 |  |
| 04.03.2021 18:37:45 |  |
| 05.03.2021 01:17:45 |  |
| 05.03.2021 10:17:45 |  |
| 05.03.2021 18:57:45 |  |

and I want to create a pivot table where all emojis are counted. So I want to know how many cloudy emojis are at the 03.03.2021. Like:

| timestamp | ☀️ |  |  |  | ⛈ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03.03.2021 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 04.03.2021 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 05.03.2021 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

But I have no idea how to count the emojis in dependent on the given date. Can someone help? All answers without a pivot table are also welcome :)

Comment: So why don't you just select your data and insert the pivot-table? It works fine for me. Make sure to use "Timestamp" for rows, and "Emoji" for both columns and values.

Comment: Your are right . With the given table it works. My table hast timestamps like '03.03.2021 17:07:45' but is only shown as '03.03.2021'. So this is the real problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by creating a second `date` column and use the formula `=DATEVALUE(A1)`. So this removes the time and allows the pivot table to use only the date to accumulate the emojis

#### Edit:

Alternatively, right click the timestamp field in the column, select Create pivot date group and select Year-Month-Day. This way an extra column is not needed.

#### Reference:

- [Create & use pivot tables](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900)

Comment: You shouldn't need an extra column, both Sheets and Excel allow you to group by date in pivot tables.

Comment: How can I group by date without the time in google sheets ?

Comment: Right click the timestamp field in the column, select Create pivot date group and select Year-Month-Day.

Comment: NICE! Thank you a lot!